# Export Blender data into directory through a directory browser

Tags: python, scripting, blender, directory-browsing

I’d like to use a *directory browser*. I’m using the `ExportHelper` class, but it pops a *file browser*. Is there anything special to turn it into a *directory browser*?

Here’s some code:

```
class ExampleExporter(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
  """My Mesh Exporter Script"""
  bl_idname      = "object.example_mesh_exporter"
  bl_label       = "Example Mesh Exporter"
  bl_description = "Export all meshes from the scene into a directory"
  bl_options     = {'REGISTER'}

  filename_ext   = ".huhu" # I don’t even need that

  sparse = BoolProperty (
      name        = "Sparse output"
    , description = "Should the output file be sparse?"
    , default     = False
    , )

  def execute(self, context):
    # do something with self.filepath
```

I don’t need `self.filepath`, I’d need something like `self.directory.`.

Comment: of course it is, in python